# How to make my function only find real worlds from permutation

Tags: c++

The code below gets a word from the user and then switches each letter around, it list all the possible combinations that it can make, I wish to filter out all the results that aren't words, I have a dictionary and words from the dictionary can get grabbed using GetWord();

an example
input `admirer`
output `married`

currently it would do

input `admirer`
output `admirre, adminerr...ect`

The following code makes this happen.

```
void Permutations(string input) {
    //sorts input for new word
    sort(input.begin(), input.end());
    do cout << input << endl; while (next_permutation(input.begin(), input.end()));
}

int FindPermutations() {
    string word;
    cout << "Input word: ";
    cin >> word;
    //Runs Premutations with given string
    Permutations(word);
    return 0;
}
```

So my question is how can I make the permutation only find real words?

Comment: It would probably be easier to iterate over each word and check if it is a permutation of your original string.

Comment: What are the arguments and return value of GetWord();

Comment: @cpp `string GetWord() {
  return (word);
 }`
and
 `void SetWord(string theWord) {
  word = theWord;
 }`

Answer (score 0):

Download an English dictionary text file from http://wordlist.sourceforge.net.
Or if you are on unix: `cat /usr/share/dict/words > words.txt`
Check if the word exists in the file to figure if its a real word. 
You could use a look up table containing the starting location of the first word of each alphabet in the file and jump to that location to optimise the search algorithm a little.

Comment: I have a dictionary text file, So I wondering how I can check that the words are real words what methods I should use.

Comment: Loop through the file . If you can find your word in the file then its a real word! To optimize just loop through only those words starting with the same alphabet as your word.